# MATLAB 2013a/b: stops responding when using UI for opening files during script execution

Tags: matlab

I've experienced under various setups that MATLAB stops responding when you try to open a file during script execution. Usually I'd just promptly kill MATLAB and start whatever I was doing before. However, now I'm working on a remote machine with a buggy OS interface that basically won't let me kill MATLAB. As the whole MATALB interface doesn't respond, I can't CTRL+C.
Is this a known issue and is there a workaround?

Comment: When Matlab is executing scrips, it can not do anything more, do not try to make him do!

Comment: Well, that basically doesn't bother me much but I use the time during script execution to check and write additional code which isn't possible when the interface doesn't respond.

Comment: while Matlab is executing the current steps, it will cue your new steps after execution (i.e. it will open your file after it finishes the current process). However, it should not cause your script to crash (unless there is some sort of memory issue)

Comment: Yeah, I know everything is basically fine. But it's so annoying if I run a long script and accidentally try to open another file in the editor which sometimes just happens.

Comment: @JohnSmith My matlab scripts run for hours in a pretty good workstation. I do not touch Matlab, and often the computer itself, because if I do, sometimes it hangs.....